# What's wrong with this logging statement?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I've recently stumbled upon the following lines of logging code in an existing application. This code looks totally wrong to me in many ways

```
Method method = ...;// passed in as parameter
//...
String className = method.getDeclaringClass().getName();
String methodName = method.getName();
long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
String msg = String.format("some text, for: %s %s in thread %d %s", className, methodName, id, name);
LOGGER.debug("xxxxxxxx {}", msg);
```

I'd like to know

- what is all wrong in this code?
- what has the biggest impact on performance?
- what is the best way for writing a logging statement such as this?

(Note: as the `{}` indicates, it's a SLF4J logger and the `xxxxxxxx` is a unique string to identify this particulary logging statement in the codebase)

Comment: *"This code looks totally wrong to me in many ways"* - in what ways? Reflection is known to be slow, so that might be a performance hit

Comment: It would have been easier and probably more efficient to use an appropriate logging pattern instead of reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logging is a cross concern in an application.
So for general case, I use interceptor/aspect pattern to do it.

```
String className = method.getDeclaringClass().getName();
String methodName = method.getName();
long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
String msg = String.format("some text, for: %s %s in thread %d %s",
              className, methodName, id, name);
```

Doing all these computations without checking before the effective level of the current logger is a non sense as it is applied even if the log is not written.
Besides, all these information can be retrieved by the API logger if required and specified in the pattern of the appender.

Besides this is not effective either :

```
String msg = String.format("some text, for: %s %s in thread %d %s", className, methodName, id, name);
LOGGER.debug("xxxxxxxx {}", msg);
```

It also formats the string before checking the level.

With the actual code, this is better :

```
if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()){
   String className = method.getDeclaringClass().getName();
   String methodName = method.getName();
   long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
   String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
   String msg = String.format("some text, for: %s %s in thread %d %s", className, methodName, id, name);
   LOGGER.debug("xxxxxxxx {}", msg);
 }
```

But a more robust solution is using pattern of appender to decorate logging information with Thread id, method, etc...

---

At last as a general way if  the check of the current level (here :`if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()){`) doesn't enclose the logging processings, for example :

```
String msg = String.format("some text, for: %s %s in thread %d %s", className, methodName, id, name);
LOGGER.debug("xxxxxxxx {}", msg);
```

It is more effective to use the log method that takes a var args as it was designed for and not as used in your sample where it defeats its purpose.

In this way it spares computations if the effective logger level doesn't match  :

```
LOGGER.debug("some text, for: {} {} in thread {} {}", className, methodName, id, name);
```